# Why does saving to .json file give an an error?

Tags: python, json, file

So I currently started a python project and the program seems to be working fine so far the .json file keeps saying I have an error

> End of file expected.json

I save the content to the file with

```
        phonebooks = {
        "First Name" : fName,
        "Last Name" : lName,
        "Phone Number" : fNumb,
        "Email" : eMail
    }

     with open("content.json", "a")as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(phonebooks))
        f.write(json.dumps("\n"))
     f.close()
```

I have no errors when running the code, it's just that the json file is marked in red

```
{"First Name": "d", "Last Name": "sg", "Phone Number": "525", "Email": "a@a"}
{"First Name": "gh", "Last Name": "g", "Phone Number": "878", "Email": "s@s"}
```

Comment: Please provide the full error traceback. Just "an error" will not help us to identify the error.

Comment: Also you don't need to use `f.close()`

Comment: Also please provide the json file you are trying to parse.

Comment: @NikhilDevadiga The JSON is written, not parsed.

Comment: What you provided is not a valid json file. It's 2 jsons smashed together.
"json file is marked in red" - you need to at least tell us where it is marked in red - your IDE, file explorer, something else? We don't have any insight into your setup so being marked in red might mean literally anything.

Comment: @matszwecja sorry this is my first time using StackOverflow, so in vs code in my project the content.json is fully in red, and at the start of the second line I have the problem that states >End of file expected.json

Comment: Well, as I said. You have 2 json strings in one .json file which is not a valid according to JSON format specs. That is why your VSCode is expecting nothing more after you close your first json object at `..."a@a"}`. Of course, you **can** use the file like that, you just have to be aware that it is not a valid .json format.

Comment: @matszwecja but later I need to be able to call and search for users, will this error bring any trouble with that later?

Comment: All depends on how you handle the file. You will not be able to do `json.load` straight from the file, but doing `json.loads` on every line should work just fine.

Comment: "I have no errors when running the code, it's just that the json file is marked in red", well, because that file is not valid JSON

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("content.json", "a")as f:
    ... # f only exist in this indented area
f.close() # f doesnt exist anymore
```